# Linux. Не могу установить пакет. Ошибка зависимости

Tags: linux, apt-get, apt, deb

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибка с доступом к ресурсу похоже. Я уже все перепробовал не получается поставить cli.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: deb файлы ставятся командой dpkg -i

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! 1. текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса. 2. это не ошибка зависимости — это совместная проблема а) взятого вами откуда-то файла и б) чего-то одного из трёх: б1) сайта, б2) вашего провайдера, б3) вашего оборудования. // ну и устанавливать пакет, содержащийся внутри скачанного из какого-то левого источника файла, надо, как и подсказано выше, программой dpkg. но лучше, конечно, левые файлы не скачивать.

Answer (score 1):

Вы пытаетесь установить скачанный пакет apt'ом. В отличии от некоторых ОС тут не надо ничего скачивать, оно само. Поэтому вам нужно просто запустить `apt install shopify-cli`, предварительно выяснив есть ли такой пакует в репозитории (`apt search shopify`).

Судя по всему команда shopyfy ошиблась в своей инструкции. Для установки уже скачанного пакета в debian based используется dpkg: `dpkg -i /path/to/download/shopify-cli-x.y.z.deb`. Ну и на самом деле они должны были бы создать репозитории со своим софтом для разных линуксов, ну да ладно.

Ну и да, командам нужен `sudo` если не root.

Да, возможно понадобится вручную установить зависимости, как описано [там](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69544004/1597497):

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ruby-full

ruby --version

sudo apt update
sudo apt install git curl autoconf bison build-essential \
    libssl-dev libyaml-dev libreadline6-dev zlib1g-dev \
    libncurses5-dev libffi-dev libgdbm6 libgdbm-dev libdb-dev
```